# Sharing state between validations in MyDslJavaValidator

Tags: xtext

The `MyDslJavaValidator` validator for my language contains a `@Check` that requires some context information from the top of the tree. I can collect that information in the check method itself, by traversing the model starting from the given element. However, since the context information does not depend on the current element, this is rather inefficient.

Is there a way of computing some state only once and have it available in all validations? I could certainly cache the state in a member variable, but as I am not sure what the lifecycle of the validator object is, I do not know if this is safe. Clearly, the information must be recomputed when the underlying model changes.

What is the best pattern to follow in such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to use "The Index" to store the information.

Outline:

- By customizing `IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy` you can put your custom information into the `userData` map of a `IEObjectDescription` which is correspond to an object near the top of the tree.
- The strategy is called everytime the resource changes. So you are always up-to date.
- Your validator can query the index for `IEObjectDescription` for the object near the top of the tree, extract the `userData` and be done.

The details for manipulating and accessing the index are explained in the section ["Linking"](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#linking).